# PROBLEMAS EN INICIAR SESION EN ANDROID STUDIO CON SPINNER

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, android-spinner

Hola amigos tengo un problema con mi login, el problema es que mi login sin que yo ponga la contraseña me envía a la otra actividad estando vació la caja de texto no me valida nada, aunque pongo una contraseña mala igual me inicia sesion creo que esta mal ubicado el evento click. ayuda por favor.

Hola amigos tengo un problema con mi login, el problema es que mi login sin que yo ponga la contraseña me envía a la otra actividad estando vació la caja de texto no me valida nada, aunque pongo una contraseña mala igual me inicia sesion creo que esta mal ubicado el evento click. ayuda por favor.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText edtPassword;
Spinner edtSucursal, edtUsuario;
Button btnLogin;

List<String> listaIdSucursales; //guarda el id de la sucursal
List<String> listaSucursales; //guarda el nombre de la sucursal

List<String> listaUsuario;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    edtSucursal = findViewById(R.id.edtSucursal);
    edtUsuario = findViewById(R.id.edtUsuario);
    edtPassword = findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
    btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    cargarSucursales();

    //uno
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            validarUsuario("http://192.168.43.91:8888/Tutoriales/spinnerDependienteAndroid/php/login.php");
        }
    });
    //dos
    edtSucursal.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String sucursal = edtSucursal.getSelectedItem().toString();
            for (int i = 0; i < listaIdSucursales.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < listaSucursales.size(); j++) {
                    if (sucursal == listaSucursales.get(i)) {
                        String idsucursal = listaIdSucursales.get(i);
                        cargarUsuarios(idsucursal);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    edtUsuario.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String usuario = edtUsuario.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Snackbar.make(view, "usuario seleccionado: " + usuario,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}


private void validarUsuario(String URL) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (!response.isEmpty()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), princioal.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "usuario o contraseña incorrecta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parametros.put("usuario", edtUsuario.getSelectedItem().toString());
            parametros.put("password", edtPassword.getText().toString());
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

public void cargarSucursales() {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://192.168.43.91:8888/Tutoriales/spinnerDependienteAndroid/php/Metodos.php?funcion=obtenerSucursales";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (response.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    obtenerSucursales(jsonArray);
                } catch (JSONException jsnex1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsnex1.toString()
                            , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
}

public void obtenerSucursales(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    listaIdSucursales = new ArrayList<String>();
    listaSucursales = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String idsucursal = jsonObject.getString("idsucursal");
            String direccion = jsonObject.getString("direccion");
            listaIdSucursales.add(idsucursal);
            listaSucursales.add(direccion);
        } catch (JSONException jsnEx2) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsnEx2.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSucursales = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listaSucursales);
    edtSucursal.setAdapter(adapterSucursales);
}

public void cargarUsuarios(String idSucursal) {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://192.168.43.91:8888/Tutoriales/spinnerDependienteAndroid/php/Metodos.php?funcion=obtenerDepartamentos&id_sucursal=" + idSucursal;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (response.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    obtenerUsuario(jsonArray);
                } catch (JSONException jsnEx4) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsnEx4.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + error.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}

public void obtenerUsuario(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    listaUsuario = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String usuario = jsonObject.getString("usuario");
            listaUsuario.add(usuario);
        } catch (JSONException jsnEx5) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsnEx5.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterUsuarios = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listaUsuario);
    edtUsuario.setAdapter(adapterUsuarios);
}
```

}

Comment: no entendí nada acerca del problema o error que estás teniendo, es bastante abierta tu pregunta

Comment: lo que pasa es que sin llenar nada en mi contraseña me inicia sesion si el campo usuario y contraseña ya estan validados

Comment: desde tu server qué valores retornas para saber que sus datos del usuario que te mandó su usuario y password son correctos? y qué regresas para saber si sus datos son incorrectos? en base a eso puedo ayudarte a modificar tu método de validar para que no te haga cosas que no

Comment: todo esta bien solo que esta mal colocado la validarUsuario del login nose cual es el orden

Comment: no te puedo ayudar con tan poca información, necesitas decirme exactamente cuál es el valor de tu respuesta para ambos casos